# A cute little group theory problem

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S$ is a subset such $|S|>|G|/2$. Then prove that for any $g\in G$ there exist elements $a,b\in S$ such that $g=ab^{-1}$.

My idea is if $G$ has the order 2 then it is trivial. If $|G|\geqslant3$ then $S$ has elements $a,b$ such that $ab^{-1}=g$ for some $g\in G$, but I cannot proceed like this. Any Hint, please?

Comment: This is more combinatorics than group theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

Consider the cardinality of $S$ and $gS$.

can you say anything about their intersection?

Comment: I think they have the same cardinality and intersection is ${{s \in S | s=gs'}}$

Comment: Yes, they have the same cardinality. Can you see that their intesection is non-empty?

Comment: yes that means g=ss'^{-1) so by this process we can vary g and conclude the result. Am I right?

Comment: yup, just represent an element in the intersection in two ways, as an element of $S$ and as an element of $gS$ and just do some manipulation to obtain the result.

Comment: thanks a lot sir :-)

Comment: @MathCosmo Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.